# How can I insert data from Excel file to Oracle using INSERT INTO SQL statement?

Tags: excel, oracle

I have created types using Oracle objects and created a table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OttawaAddress_Ty AS OBJECT
(StrtNum NUMBER(9),
Street VARCHAR2(20),
City VARCHAR2(15),
Province CHAR(2),
PostalCode CHAR(7));
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OttawaOfficesInfo_Ty AS OBJECT
(Name VARCHAR(35),
OfficeID VARCHAR2(2),
Phone VARCHAR2(15),
Fax CHAR(15),
Email CHAR(30));
/


CREATE TABLE OttawaOffices
(OfficeAddress OttawaAddress_Ty,
OfficeInfo OttawaOfficesInfo_Ty,
Longitude_DMS NUMBER (10,7),
Latitude_DMS NUMBER (10,7),
SDO_GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

I have an Excel file which holds the data and I need to import to this Oracle table using INSERT INTO SQL statements. How can I do this? As you can notice, I have a column called `SDO_GEOMETRY` which will hold the Decimal Degrees of the records. These decimal degrees are saved in two separate columns in my Excel file.

I am not sure if I can problematically insert the values from Excel or whether I need to go through every record and create
INSERT INTO ... VALUES.... And if so, how to add values when I have created types?

Comment: You should Google on something like "Excel VBA pass-through Query to Oracle" and then adjust the findings for your particular requirements. Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a really neat feature called External Tables.  These look like regular tables from inside the database, so we can execute SELECT statements against them.  The trick is that the table's data domes from OS files (hence "external").  We just define the table to say the same structure as the spreadsheet's columns.  It doesn't work with Excel binary format but it does work for CSV files (so `Save as ...`).

The advantage of external tables is that manipulating data is easy in SQL - it's what it just best - and we don't need to load anything into a staging table.  Something like

```
insert into OttawaOffices
select  ottawaaddress_ty(ext.strtnum,ext.street,ext.city,ext.province,ext.postalcode)
     , ottawaofficesinfo_ty (ext.name,ext.officeid,ext.phone,ext.fax,ext.email)
     , ext.longitude
     , ext.latitude
     , SDO_GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(ext.col1, ext.col2)
from your_external_table ext
/
```

The limitation of external tables is the need to get the source file onto the database server and create a database directory object.  Some places are funny about this.

Anyway, [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-309085A3-9D23-4ED8-9920-E243C6406286.htm#SUTIL999).

---

I'm not going to pass judgement on the declaring table columns as user-defined types.  It's usually considered bad practice but maybe it works in your use case.